# problems with Stateless session bean with EJB3.0 and websphere6.1

Tags: session, ejb-3.0, javabeans, stateless

**I am not able to create Stateless session bean with EJB3.0 and Websphere 6.1.

I package everything in EAR file and deployed it on Websphere .
I am trying to create a Stateless Session bean and expecting it to instantiate session    bean and call ejbCreate().**

```
Following is my code and xml file.

package com.aa.otrs.datacollector.reject.ejb;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;
import com.aa.otrs.datacollector.logging.DataCollectorLogger;
import com.aa.otrs.fraudnet.service.FraudNetSoapWrapperService;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

@Stateless
@Interceptors(GuiceInterceptor.class)
public class RejectServiceBean implements IRejectServiceBean{

     @Inject
     private DataCollectorLogger logger;
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     @Inject
            private FraudNetSoapWrapperService fraudnetWebService;
     @Resource
     private TimerService timerService;

     public void ejbCreate() throws javax.ejb.CreateException {
         logger.debug("On ejbCreate");
         logger.debug(“RejectServiceBean ");

     }

     public void ejbActivate() {
         logger.debug("ejbActivate");
     }

}

This is ibm-ejb-jar-bnd xml file under META-INF folder.

<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <message-driven name="PnrMessageBean">
        <listener-port name="RECLOCATOR.LP" />
    </message-driven>

    <session name="RejectServiceBean">
    <interface class="com.aa.otrs.datacollector.reject.ejb.IRejectServiceBean" 
                binding-name="ejblocal:ejb/RejectServiceBean"/>
    </session>

</ejb-jar-bnd>

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface IRejectServiceBean {

    void callingInterface();
}

I have tried implementing stateless session with or without interface and xml file. 

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TimedObject;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;
import com.aa.otrs.datacollector.logging.DataCollectorLogger;
import com.aa.otrs.fraudnet.service.FraudNetSoapWrapperService;


@Stateless
@Interceptors(GuiceInterceptor.class)
public class RejectServiceSessionBean {
     @Inject
     private DataCollectorLogger logger;
     @Inject
     private FraudNetSoapWrapperService fraudnetWebService;


     public void ejbCreate() throws javax.ejb.CreateException {
         logger.debug("On ejbCreate");
         logger.debug("In RejectServiceSessionBean constructor");

     }
     public void ejbActivate() {
         logger.debug("ejbActivate");
     }


public class GuiceInterceptor{
       private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EjbEnvironmentModule());

       @PostConstruct
       @PostActivate
       public void autowireBean(InvocationContext invocationContext) {
           Object target = invocationContext.getTarget();
           injector.injectMembers(target);
       }


    }
```

Problem: From above two code snippet it never makes calls to ejbCreate or ejbActivate       method.
I have put the loggers so that I can verify if it goes through these methods.

Answer (score 0):

For EJB-3.0 stateless bean, you can have lifecycle callback methods by using `@PostConstruct` & `@PreDestroy` annotation.

These methods must be public, return void & without any parameters.